# Is urban exploration on-topic?

Tags: discussion, scope

Recently, two questions on urban exploration / urban geocaching were asked:

- *[How to deal with aggressive homeless when exploring urbex?](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/5557/how-to-deal-with-aggressive-clochards-when-exploring-urbex)*
- *[Urbex question: How to protect myself from asbestos?](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/q/5561/566)*

Are such questions on-topic on The Great Outdoors?

Comment: I have already commented [here](https://meta.outdoors.stackexchange.com/a/478/2410) why I think that especially those two questions are not really good questions for this site at all – independent of the question, whether we should include urbex or not.

Comment: One thing that needs to be borne in mind around these question is Urban exploring is highly illegal in many countries (My country included). Anyone caught in an abandoned building in the UK is likely to spend the night in a cell. So should we be encouraging potentially illegal behaviour?

Comment: I recently posted a question about `urbex` in outdoors.stackexchange and was quite popular, then it was migrated to law.stackexchange and pretty much died... So, I guess it's still a grey area.

Answer (score 12):

There are many arguments for including Urbex in the scope of The Great Outdoors:

- Urbex is active form of spending free time outside your house
- it includes intensive physical activity
- many urbex constructions, like abandoned railways, are in the nature
- getting to abandoned objects often requires crossing hard bush terrain
- the equipment and abilities needed are very similar to those used by climbing, speleology, backpacking, survival
- the large cross-over with geocaching, parkour and survival
- similar target audience: people involved in urbex are highly likely to invoke in many other outdoor disciplines

Answer (score 11):

While I would class Urban Exploration as on topic, and have upvoted your answer here, neither of those questions is on topic, as Benedikt commented.

Mentioning an on-topic subject in a question does not automatically make that question on-topic.

So this meta question's headline - "Is Urban Exploration on-topic" - could be answered with a definite **Yes** from me, but the two questions you linked to would be a definite **No**

Comment: While I tend to agree with your argument, I believe that these two questions suffers from the fact that these new tags are unpopular and without (yet?) many followers. If this was a main topic, would people be more receptive / lenient? I believe so, as those questions may not appear relevant from the outside, but may be quite on-topic and fruitful for the interested parties.

Comment: I don't think that is the problem, ppl. I am definitely an interested party in urban exploration, but those questions are not about urban exploration at all.

Comment: The second question clearly deals with the safety of urbex which I disagree with your statement that it is "*not about urban exploration at all*".

Comment: Okay, I'd have to completely disagree with you on this. Would having 'how would i deal with asbestos as an artist working in old buildings?' make it an art question? No.

Comment: Let me make a point by referencing an undisputable source (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Urban_exploration); "*Asbestos is a long term health risk for urban explorers, along with breathing in contaminants from dried bird feces, which can cause a condition known as pigeon lung, a form of hypersensitivity pneumonitis.*". I believe it is more relevant than one might think. The boat question does not quite fit the mold in this case, imho.

Comment: This discussion reminds me a little of stackoverflows [boat-programming question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/14470/what-is-the-boat-programming-meme-about)... However, I think, the questions are perfectly on topic. Otherwhise any question about hypothermia should be asked in a medical forum, [this](http://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/3433/how-do-i-mount-a-hangboard-in-an-apartment?rq=1) question should be asked in a home improvement forum and so on...You run into these problems doing this activities, so they should be allowed to ask. They do no harm.