# Survival tag wiki

Tags: discussion, scope, community-wiki

I'm considering editing the [survival](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/survival) to make it clear that any survival questions must be related to *"the great outdoors"* and not survival in urban areas, etc.

I'm thinking something along the lines of:

> Questions relating to staying alive in the **wilderness** and learning
>   survival techniques.
>
> Please **do not** use this tag for questions about general survival
>   that are not related to the outdoors. Surviving in town or city
>   environments will likely be closed.

does this seem ok with everyone?

We've already decided that [urbex is on topic](https://outdoors.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/479/is-urban-exploration-on-topic). I'm more concerned with questions such as this:

- [Getting Under Bed During An Earthquake](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/7742/getting-under-bed-during-an-earthquake)

Comment: I agree, that question is not on topic within the scope of the great outdoors so we should change the tag to be less general and more outdoors.

Comment: that specific question is probably better on Skeptics - I'll ask if they want it

Comment: I've done this now.